# Remotely check who is logged in by NETBIOS name

Tags: windows, command-line

I manage a network and I am trying to figure out who is using a machine with a specific NETBIOS name because it appears to be mislabeled physically on the exterior of the box.

I am wondering what, if any, tool I can use from my server or workstation to see who is currently logged into a machine.

I know about Query User but that only works for RDP sessions I believe.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `Query User` will show the console session as well. Did you try it?

Comment: Here is the output when I try to query the remote machine:


`C:\Windows\system32>Query User /server:pawn31.corp.[company].com
Error 0x000006BA enumerating sessionnames
Error [1722]:The RPC server is unavailable.`

Comment: Is it's firewall up? If so, you're probably not going to have much luck doing anything from remote. :/

Comment: Shouldn't be I guess my only move is to add firewall exceptions to group policy and have it update tomorrow on start-up then try again maybe?

Comment: @techie007: Workstation versions of Windows disallow remote RPC by default, even if it passes through the firewall. (On the other hand, Remote Registry should be available, and it can be used to change that setting remotely.)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
ping NETBIOSNAME
```

to find the IP address of the mystery box.  Your network folk should then be able to track the physical location for you.

Comment: Heh.  I am the network guy also and I know the IP.  That isn't the problem.

Comment: Given the IP address you can find the MAC address, and from the MAC address you should be able to identify the switch port, and then it's just a matter of following cables.  (Won't work if you're using bargain-basement cheap switches though.)

Comment: Another option, if you have a file server, is to look for the machine in question in Computer Management:System Tools:Shared Folders:Sessions.  That maps users to machines.

Answer (score 1):

As a response to Nolan Berry's comment to sgmoore's answer, I found a solution to the, "Error 5 getting sessionnames Error [5]:Access is denied." problem when using query session.

Use regedit to set the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\AllowRemoteRPC value to 1.

I got the answer from here:
http://blog.umito.nl/2010/02/20/solution-to-msg-exe-error-5-getting-session-names.html/comment-page-1

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

From your server, either **net session** or **query session** should give you the info.

Comment: I am getting this when I attempt to query session:

`C:\Windows\system32>query session /SERVER:10.1.1.138
Error 5 getting sessionnames
Error [5]:Access is denied.`

This isn't a huge deal but it is fairly annoying.  Also worth noting I have Domain admin creds.